# Relacionar arquivo JavaScript em um HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

sou iniciante no mundo Node, e estou com dificuldades em relacionar um arquivo .js em um HTML.

peguei um código simples, nele tenho um combobox que é preenchido ao pressionar um botão:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile('page.html', {root:__dirname});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Este é o código que quero por no HTML:

```
//page.js
document.getElementById("btnCarregar").onclick = function () {
var comboCidades = document.getElementById("cboCidades");

var opt0 = document.createElement("option");
opt0.value = "0";
opt0.text = "";
comboCidades.add(opt0, comboCidades.options[0]);

var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
opt1.value = "scs";
opt1.text = "São Caetano do Sul";
comboCidades.add(opt1, comboCidades.options[1]);

var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
opt2.value = "sa";
opt2.text = "Santo André";
comboCidades.add(opt2, comboCidades.options[2]);

var opt3 = document.createElement("option");
opt3.value = "sbc";
opt3.text = "São Bernardo do Campo";
comboCidades.add(opt3, comboCidades.options[3]);
};
```

E o respectivo HTML:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>
            <select id="cboCidades"></select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="btnCarregar" value="Carregar combobox" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <script src="page.js"></script>
</body>
```

Então...se eu iniciar o servidor, e acessar o localhost:3000, a página é carregada normalmente, porém o botão não funciona pois ele não consegue utilizar o código do .js externo e no console do navegador fica aparecendo essa mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas...se eu simplesmente abrir o arquivo HTML o botão funciona normalmente.

Eu gostaria de entender o motivo de não funcionar ao acessar o localhost:3000 e quais as possíveis soluções.

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom para que o arquivo `page.js` seja carregado você deve mapear uma pasta para arquivos estáticos no express.

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, criar uma pasta `public` e dizer ao express que ela vai ser sua pasta de arquivos estáticos e dentro dela você coloca o arquivo `page.js`. Isso também vale para css e imagens que forem chamadas na paginas com base href do seu localhost. Você também pode criar subpastas dentro do diretório estatico como pasta js, css, assets, img, etc.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Veja que desta forma a pasta public vai estar no mesmo diretório de app.js, caso esteja em diretórios diferentes deve ser mapeado com base no caminho absoluto.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile('page.html', {root:__dirname});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

No seu script:

```
<script src="/page.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Por um breve momento achei que não fosse necessário servir estaticamente os arquivos, pois em todos os sites onde pesquisei davam a entender que eu deveria simplesmente passar o diretório do .js na tag script.

Comment: Bom dia, uma das vantagens que eu vejo no express é que se você não definir nas configurações, ele não faz, isso vale para o body, headers, arquivos estáticos, response, status code, etc.